# Which HSQLDB Data Type is Optimal for 5000 Character String: NTEXT, CLOB or Other.?

Tags: hsqldb

I need to store messages of length between 1 and 4200 characters in my database.
Should I create the column with "...NAMEHERE CLOB(5000) NOT NULL, ..." or "...NAMEHERE NTEXT NOT NULL", or is something else optimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with both VARCHAR(5000) and CLOB(5000). Performance depends on the type of database and table. If your database is all in-memory `mem:`, use VARCHAR(5000). For `file:`databases CLOB(5000) uses less memory and should perform better in a large database.

The difference is in the file where the data for this column is stored. With VARCHAR(5000) it is stored together with other columns. With CLOB(5000) it is stored in the separate `.lobs` file.

If you use CLOB, change the LOB SCALE with `SET FILES LOB SCALE 2` to allocate the file spaces in units of 2 kilobytes and reduce waste.

Comment: varchar has a limit thats somewhere around 230 and 240 for hsql.. I ended up using CLOB(5000) just as is and it works just fine. Thanks anyways

Comment: There is no such limit with VARCHAR in HSQLDB.

Comment: Turns out you are right. It says nvarchar(max)'s max is 230 in here but I guess it means something else: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hsqldb/hsqldb_data_types.htm Thank you...

Comment: The linked page has used information about Microsoft SQL Server for HSQLDB. Use the (http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_data_type_guide) HyperSQ Guide.